# expo unknown option --force

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

I tried to install expo-notifications package using:

```
expo install expo-notifications
```

but it gives me dependency errors listed below. But when i try to run with --force, it gives me:

> error: unknown option `--force'

This command is being executed with the global Expo CLI. Learn more: https://blog.expo.dev/the-new-expo-cli-f4250d8e3421
To use the local CLI instead (recommended in SDK 46 and higher),
run:
› npx expo install

Installing 1 SDK 47.0.0 compatible native module using npm.

> npm install
> npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use
> `--location=global` instead.
> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
> npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! While resolving: @homee/react-native-mapbox-navigation@1.1.0
> npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
> npm ERR! node_modules/react
> npm ERR!   react@"18.1.0" from the root project
> npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.3.0" from @callstack/react-theme-provider@3.0.8
> npm ERR!   node_modules/@callstack/react-theme-provider
> npm ERR!     @callstack/react-theme-provider@"^3.0.8" from react-native-paper@5.2.0
> npm ERR!     node_modules/react-native-paper
> npm ERR!       react-native-paper@"^5.2.0" from the root project
> npm ERR!   32 more (@expo/react-native-action-sheet, ...)
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
> npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.1" from @homee/react-native-mapbox-navigation@1.1.0
> npm ERR! node_modules/@homee/react-native-mapbox-navigation
> npm ERR!   @homee/react-native-mapbox-navigation@"^1.1.0" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
> npm ERR! node_modules/react
> npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.1" from @homee/react-native-mapbox-navigation@1.1.0
> npm ERR!   node_modules/@homee/react-native-mapbox-navigation
> npm ERR!     @homee/react-native-mapbox-navigation@"^1.1.0" from
> the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
> npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
> npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! See C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-04-30T09_32_04_685Z-debug-0.log

npm exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: npm exited with non-zero code: 1
at ChildProcess.completionListener (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:65:13)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
...
at spawnAsync (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:26:19)    at NpmPackageManager._runAsync (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\package-manager\src\NodePackageManagers.ts:166:31)
at NpmPackageManager.installAsync (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\package-manager\src\NodePackageManagers.ts:82:16)
at NpmPackageManager.addWithParametersAsync (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\package-manager\src\NodePackageManagers.ts:96:18)
at actionAsync (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\inst\src\commands\installAsync.ts:143:3)

Answer (score 0):

The official document states that installation is no longer necessary through `npm global install`.

so you first local expo remove  `npm uninstall -g expo`

you can use `npx create-expo-app my-app`

and

ref : https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/

`npx expo install expo-notifications`